# With ARC will I ever need to manage memory manually?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

my question is basically the title. In XCode with Automatic Reference Counting turned on, will I ever need to manage memory manually? Like calling release, retain, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: In ARC, u need not to worry about releasing memory.but be aware object does not get released at the time of using it.

Comment: @Prince: When does the object get released?

Comment: @Surfbutler at an arbitrary point in the future. It'll be deterministic but not explicit from your syntax, other than that you'll implicitly supply upper lifetime bounds. So things like Guard Malloc and Zombies should reliably catch problems and performance should be predictable but writing code that assumes when a release will occur is a bad idea — though it's always been a bad idea for a variety of reasons. Follow the `NSTimer` pattern with an `invalidate`-type step if you need to tell someone explicitly when to stop doing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARC handles only Objective-C objects. So you'll need to continue manually to manage Core Foundation and plain C memory.

Although you shouldn't need manually to retain or release you're also still in charge of preventing retain cycles — ensuring you flag appropriate properties as strong and weak. So you'll need to continue to consider at least that aspect of ownership.

Beyond that there's at least one very specific quirk — you'll need to remember to copy blocks if the stack is going to unwind underneath them. That's to ensure they end up on the heap rather than the stack so is memory management related.

Comment: In some situations (such as assigning a block to a property, or returning one from a function), blocks are automagically copied, but I wouldn't rely upon it.

Comment: I think they're also copied when captured by other blocks so that's 99% of real use cases covered but I've yet to find any citeable reference that e.g. passing one as the object to a `performSelector:...afterDelay:` would be safe.

Comment: no, just arbitrarily passing a block as an object to another function is `not` safe, and let me explain why: Blocks are automatically copied when they are passed into a function which already copies objects (e.g.) properties, but they aren't retained like normal objects. So, while I may have a `strong` reference to a block, unless that block is on the heap that means nothing. Blocks do not get copied when assigning to an arbitrary type (`id`), because ARC doesn't know you want to use `copy` vs `retain` (which only works when the block has already been copied). Blocks are very confusing.